# Disable <.>(Previous, Next ) buttons from iOS Default keyboard

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

1. I am having a html form loaded in a webview.
2. When I click on the textfield , the keyboard appears
3. After entering a text field , click on the next input field and enter some text.
   The keyboard appears with <,>( previous , next buttons) that navigate through the html form.

Is there any way to disable the next and previous buttons. I do not want them to display on my keyboard.

This is disabled if we turn them off in Settings-> General -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Toggle OFF
But Can we do this programmatically in a webview?
Or is there some solution to disable the buttons in keyboard?

Sample code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{

   string path = NSBundle.MainBundle.ResourcePath;
   string htmlpath = Path.Combine(path, "Welcome.html");

   webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(htmlpath, true)));
}
```

Expected Behavior:
The <,>(Previous, Next ) buttons form the keyboard should not be visible when html form is loaded in a webview.

Actual Behavior:
When a html form is being filled, the keyboard shows next, previous buttons to navigate the form.